# AS2 Multi string replace

Tags: php, mysql, string, flash, actionscript-2

Newbie here :)

First my AS2 code:

```
txt.html=true;
txt.htmlText="This is an example: www.sample.com is not www.othersample.com";
var sampleText:String=findUrl(txt.text);
trace(sampleText);
function findUrl(str){
    var rawURL:Array = new Array();
    rawURL = str.split(' ');
    for(var i=0; i<rawURL.length; i++) {
        if(rawURL[i].indexOf("http://") != -1 or rawURL[i].indexOf("www.") != -1)    {
            return (str.replace(rawURL[i], "<a href='"+rawURL[i]+"' target='_blank'><u><font color='#666666'>"+rawURL[i]+"</font></u></a>"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This is an example: <a href='www.sample.com' target='_blank'><u><font color='#666666'>www.sample.com</font></u></a> is not www.othersample.com
```

First question is why my flash function always replace only first url?

What I'm trying to do is send string from flash input textfield by PHP to mySQL table. Then, when flash will load it again all urls in my flash textfield will be clickable.

Of course I can use preg_replace in PHP:

```
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$comments = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2", $comments);
$comments = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i", "<u><A TARGET=\"_blank\" HREF=\"$1\"><font color=\"#666666\">$1</font></A></u>", $comments);
```

but the problem is that this string is editable in flash, so when I send it (edited) back to PHP, PHP overwriting links and make them unreadable for flash (example):

```
<u><a target="_blank" href="<u><a target="_blank" href="http://asdasd.asdasd.pl"><font color="#666666">http://asdasd.asdasd.pl</font></a></u>"><font color="#666666"><u><a target="_blank" href="http://asdasd.asdasd.pl"><font color="#666666">http://asdasd.asdasd.pl</font></a></u></font></a></u>
```

I can also use some PHP function which will check whether sended data from flash already contains clickable url's, but if I need add another link in edited string, preg_replace not fire then...

Is there any way to do what I need?

Thanks in advance,
Artur.

Comment: If the app can be written in AS3, you can duplicate your regexp and use it in your flash piece, otherwise, the issue regarding findURL is based on the return statement in your loop.  You are returning at the first instance, thus it never hits the second occurrence.

Comment: It can't be writen in AS3, my whole project is writen in AS2 :(

Comment: mmm...adds a few lines of code...1 min :P

Comment: If you have source file... Unfortunately my project is a flash module for AS2 project to which I have no FLA file ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[EDIT]]

Line 32 changed from:

```
last = lowest.end;
```

to:

```
last = lowest.end + idx;
```

---

As I mentioned in the comment...really blows the code out a little.  The alternative is to pull in an existing AS2 regexp library.  Last I looked (5 years ago), the AS2 regexp implementations were not 100% with regards to expression support.  I'm sure there is a shorter way of going about this, but here is the code after a first attempt:

```
String.prototype.replace = function(search:String, replace:String):String
{
    return this.split(search).join(replace);
}

function linkPaths(text:String, template:String):String
{
    var idx:Number;
    var lowest:Object;

    var selectors:Array =
    [
        "http://",
        "www."
    ];

    var sub:String;
    var last:Number = 0;
    var result:String = "";

    for(idx=0; idx<text.length; idx++)
    {
        sub = text.substring(idx);
        lowest = findLowestSelector(sub, selectors);

        if(!lowest)
        {
            break;
        }

        result += text.substring(last, lowest.start + idx) + template.replace("${url}", sub.substring(lowest.start, lowest.end));
        last = lowest.end + idx;
        idx += lowest.end;
    }

    return result;
}

function findLowestSelector(text:String, selectors:Array):Object
{
    var idx:Number;
    var index:Number;

    var start:Number = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var end:Number = -1;

    for(idx=0; idx<selectors.length; idx++)
    {
        index = text.indexOf(selectors[idx]);

        if
        (
            index != -1 &&
            index < start
        )
        {
            start = index;

            index = text.indexOf(" ", start);
            end = index == -1 ? text.length : index ;
        }
    }

    return start != -1 ?
        {
            start: start,
            end: end
        }
        :
        null
    ;
}

trace(linkPaths
(
    "test text here http://www.test.com is a link, along with www.test.com",
    "<a href='${url}' target='_blank'><u><font color='#666666'>${url}</font></u></a>"
));
```

Let me know if there are any issues.  The findLowestSelector method uses a single blank space, or end of line to dictate the end value in the return object.

Been a while since I've worked with AS2...

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot that you spend your time for me :) I'll check this out and give you know whether I can do something with this in my project.

Comment: So far I can see that your code return properly maximum 2 links. Depends on how much more (than 2) links exists in string - links begin looping and pullulating themself. But it's good start point. As it works for 2 links, it should also work for multi links, so I'll study your code trying find out the magic you've done here. Thanks Again.

Comment: Glad to have helped.  It will work with as many links as you can throw at it.  There are some limitations as it requires at least one space between links.  If there aren't any issues, could you please upvote and accept my answer? :)

Comment: Like I wrote previously, it works properly for maximum 2 links in string with spaces between urls. Eg: "www.test.com www.test1.com www.test2.com" will return 3 clickable links, but www.test1.com will be double and not clickable. With 4 links in string it will return 4 clickable and 3 not clickable links mixed together, and so on...

Comment: interesting, let me take a quick look, prob an index issue :P

Comment: source edited.  problem was on line 32.  change it to the following:

last = lowest.end + idx;

Comment: Yes, it's working now. You didn't give me time to study your code :) . Thanks a lot for your time and patience.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5391/discussion-between-stat-and-phillip100)

Answer (score 0):

Found also other solution - by PHP.

function **between_replace** got there: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#104072

Code:

```
<?
$sample=$_POST['sample'];

$sample = ereg_replace("[\]", "", $sample);
between_replace ('<u><a target="_blank" href="','">', $sample, "");
$sample = str_replace('<u><a target="_blank" href="', "", $sample);
$sample = str_replace('"><font color="#666666">http://', "", $sample);
$sample = str_replace("</font></a></u>", "", $sample);
$sample = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2", $sample);
$sample = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i", "<u><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\"><font color=\"#666666\">$1</font></a></u>", $sample);
$sample = preg_replace("/([\w-?&;#~=\.\/]+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?))/i","<u><a href=\"mailto:$1\"><font color=\"#666666\">$1</font></a></u>",$sample); 
$sample = ereg_replace("[\n]", "\n", $sample);
$sample = ereg_replace("[']", "''", $sample);

echo "&sampletext=" . $sample."&";

function between_replace ($open, $close, &$in, $with, $limit=false, $from=0)
{
if ($limit!==false && $limit==0)
{
    return $in;
}        
$open_position = strpos ($in, $open, $from);
if ($open_position===false)
{
    return false;
};
$close_position = strpos ($in, $close, $open_position+strlen($open));
if ($close_position===false)
{
    return false;
};
$current = false;
if (strpos($with,'{*}')!==false)
{
    $current = substr ($in, $open_position+strlen($open), $close_position-$open_position-strlen($open));
    $current = str_replace ('{*}',$current,$with);
    //debug_echo ($current);
}
else
{
    $current = $with;
}
$in = substr_replace ($in, $current, $open_position+strlen($open), $close_position-$open_position-strlen($open));
$next_position = $open_position + strlen($current) + 1;
if ($next_position>=strlen($in))
{
    return false;
}
if ($limit!==false)
{
    $limit--;
}        
between_replace ($open, $close, $in, $with, $limit, $next_position);
return $in;
}
?>
```